# Norm of projection onto functions of mean zero

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a finite set and consider the space $\ell^2(X;Y)$ of functions $\zeta:X\to Y$, where $Y$ is a fixed Banach space. It decomposes into a direct sum of constant function and its complement $\ell_{2,0}(X;Y)$, the subspace of functions satisfying $$\sum_{x\in X} \zeta(x)=0.$$
The projection $Q$ onto $\ell^{2,0}(X;Y)$ is $$Q\zeta(x)=\zeta(x)-|X|^{-1}\sum_{s\in X} \zeta(s).$$
For $Y$ a Hilbert space $Q$ is an orthogonal projection.

**Question:** For which Banach spaces $Y$ does $Q$ have norm 1?